# Unity 3D -- Failed to sign APK - while i have given correct keystore and password

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, apk, sign

### i was building my sign apk, there was no issue. but suddenly its start giving me error of "Failed to sign APK Package."

my keystore is correct,
password is correct,

### alias is correct....

## ** **This is the error below** **

Failed to sign APK package.
D:\Plugins\Android_SDK\build-tools\27.0.3\apksigner.bat sign --ks "G:/__KeyStore/ormeoo.keystore" --ks-pass stdin  --ks-key-alias "ormeoo" --key-pass stdin  "F:\Projects\Current Working_2\OR - 98% Impossible Monster Car\Temp/StagingArea/Package.apk"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another work around;

Try changing the Build System to Gradle (New) instead of Internal (Default).

Hope it helps..